# changing class and getting numbers

Tags: r, dataset, logic, numeric, hypothesis-test

I am working with the golub dataset in R (separated by the AML and ALL) and I am attempting to do a hypothesis test in relation to two genes. For the AML patient group, I want to find out the proportion of patients who have a higher expression of gene 900 as compared to gene 1000, then I want to see if that out of those who have a higher expression value for gene 900, the number is less than half. I have a general idea to do the other half, and I had something like this for the first part, but seeing as its T/F I tried to switch it to numeric which gave 0 and 1 but I want the actual numbers and not in the logical form.

```
`gol.fac <- factor(golub.cl,levels=0:1, labels= c("ALL","AML"))
 x <- golub[900,gol.fac=="AML"]
 y <- golub[1000,gol.fac=="AML"]
 z <-golub[900,gol.fac=="AML"] > golub[1000,gol.fac=="AML"]
 k <- as.numeric(z)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `max`

```
max(golub[900,gol.fac=="AML"], golub[1000,gol.fac=="AML"])
```

Or if you have multiple values then use `pmax`

```
pmax(golub[900,gol.fac=="AML"], golub[1000,gol.fac=="AML"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing multiple slices of rows, just get the `max` by subsetting once

```
max(golub[900:1000, "AML"])
```